# System.InvalidCastException - works in debug, fails at release

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
06-11 19:39:01.690 I/MonoDroid(17577):   at MyApp.Inbox.CorrespondenceActivity.CorrectLinkPaths (ISpanned spanText) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

That is the exception I'm getting. When building the application with Debug configuration, everything works alright - no exceptions, no nothing. Once I build it for release, I get this exception - and I can't figure out why, and how to fix it.

This is the code that invokes the method CorrectLinkPaths:

```
_someTextView.SetText(CorrectLinkPaths(Html.FromHtml(_myMessage.Summary + "\n\n" + _myMessage.Body)), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

Needless to say, _myMessage.Summary and Body are HTML-strings.

My CorrectLinkPaths-method looks like this:

```
private ISpanned CorrectLinkPaths(ISpanned spanText)
    {
        Object[] spans = spanText.GetSpans(0, spanText.Length(), Class.FromType(typeof (Object)));
        foreach (var s in spans)
        {
            int start = spanText.GetSpanStart(s);
            int end = spanText.GetSpanEnd(s);
            SpanTypes flags = spanText.GetSpanFlags(s);
            if (s.GetType() == typeof (URLSpan))
            {
                var urlSpan = (URLSpan) s;
                if (!urlSpan.URL.StartsWith("http"))
                {
                    if (urlSpan.URL.StartsWith("/"))
                        urlSpan = new URLSpan("http://www.mydomain.com" + urlSpan.URL);
                    else
                        urlSpan = new URLSpan("http://www.mydomain.com/" + urlSpan.URL);
                }
                ((ISpannable) spanText).RemoveSpan(s);
                ((ISpannable) spanText).SetSpan(urlSpan, start, end, flags);
            }
        }
        return spanText;
    }
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why this works during debug, but fails when I try to build for release, and how to fix it? I would be very, very, very grateful!

Thank you :)

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was fairly simple. It was the casting at the bottom of the method that resulted in the error

```
((ISpannable) spanText).RemoveSpan(s);
((ISpannable) spanText).SetSpan(urlSpan, start, end, flags);
```

To work around this the method had to be changed to the following:

```
public ISpanned CorrectLinkPaths(ISpanned spanText)
{
    Object[] spans = spanText.GetSpans(0, spanText.Length(), Class.FromType(typeof (Object)));
    ISpannable spanned = new SpannableString(spanText);
    foreach (var s in spans)
    {
        var start = spanText.GetSpanStart(s);
        var end = spanText.GetSpanEnd(s);
        var flags = spanText.GetSpanFlags(s);

        if (s.GetType() == typeof (URLSpan))
        {
            var urlSpan = (URLSpan)s;
            if (!urlSpan.URL.StartsWith("http"))
            {
                if (urlSpan.URL.StartsWith("/"))
                    urlSpan = new URLSpan("http://www.mydomain.com" + urlSpan.URL);
                else
                    urlSpan = new URLSpan("http://www.mydomain.com/" + urlSpan.URL);
            }
            spanned.RemoveSpan(s);
            spanned.SetSpan(urlSpan, start, end, flags);
        }
    }
    return spanned;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaCast, it works in release and debug mode. You will have to include namespace Android.Runtime.

```
spanText.JavaCast<ISpannable>().RemoveSpan(s);
spanText.JavaCast<ISpannable>().SetSpan(urlSpan, start, end, flags);
```