# C# Cast works only in debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, casting, xamarin.android

I’m developing a mobile application which among other things, it receives data from medical devices via Bluetooth. To this end, I’m using an Android SDK in JAR via binding to my Xamarin project. Here’s the class that holds the returned data from the decompiled JAR:

```
package com.contec.jar.contec08a;
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class DeviceData
    {
      public ArrayList<byte[]> mData_blood = new ArrayList();
      public ArrayList<byte[]> mData_oxygen = new ArrayList();
      public ArrayList<byte[]> mData_normal_blood = new ArrayList();
    }
```

What is of interest is the mData_blood. Each element of the array list corresponds to a patient. Each byte array is the medical data for each patient. The Xamarin framework makes some changes, i.e. the name of the property becomes MDataBlood.

**Problem**: when I receive the above class and property, the casting fails BUT NOT in the debugger. Here’s what I mean: the ‘as’ operator that implement the cast fails (returns null) but in the debugger the very same expression correctly shows the data. 
What’s more, the ‘is’ operator returns false in runtime (the canDo variable is false) but true in the debugger. I’ve tried all methods of casting I’m familiar with, even using –but not mixing – Android objects. The highlighted line which casts the IList to List produces a nice exception. I’m at a total loss. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the screenshot from the debugger which illustrates all the above:

[image: Debugger session screenshot.]

Edit1: The MDataBlood[0] evaluates as generic Java object. When reviewing its properties, its isArray is set to true. By checking the decompiled source of the SDK, I determined that is indeed byte array.

Comment: Have you tried building the `byte[]` manually by iterating through `MDataBlood[0]`?

Comment: Can you evaluate dm.MDeviceData.MDataBlood[0].GetType().Fullname at both run time and debug time and see what each of them says?

Comment: Please @Manos Georgoudakis share with us how to achive the cast. I can't even do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xamarin, there are some castings that might fail when the objects come from java types. In that cases you should use [JavaCast<TResult>](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast%7BTResult%7D/p/Android.Runtime.IJavaObject/) instead of a regular casting.

Try this, instead of your current approach:

```
// Since MDataBlood is exposed as an IList property of MDeviceData,
// we first need to cast it to IJavaObject
var dataBloodRaw = (IJavaObject)dm.MDeviceData.MDataBlood;

// Then we have access to its JavaCast method
var dataBlood = dataBloodRaw.JavaCast<JavaList<byte[]>>();
```

[`JavaList<T>`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Runtime.JavaList/) extends `Java.Lang.Object`, so it can be used as the `TResult` parameter for `JavaCast<TResult>`. Also, it implements `IList`, so you should be able to loop through it.

Anyway, if you need a `List<byte[]>` you can use the casted `JavaList` for creating it:

```
var dataBloodList = dataBlood.ToList();
```

Or, alternatively

```
var dataBloodList = new List<byte[]>(dataBlood);
```

Yet another thing you could just try is to Java-cast `dataBloodRaw` to a `JavaList<object>` and then loop through its objects, trying to cast each one of them as a `byte[]`.

**Plan B**

If none of the above works, I suggest you to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30808322/370798) where it is suggested to **disable [linking](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/) for Release**, which can be done in your project properties:

[image]

Keep in mind that a side effect of this last option will be the impact on the final size of your application.

Comment: Javacast seems to point to the right direction. Can't apply it like you mention because dataBlood is IList and thus does not contain definition of JavaCast, hence I' m trying one level above.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `dm.MDeviceData.MDataBlood`'s type is `Android.Runtime.JavaList` so it should contain the `JavaCast` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, MDataBlood is IList and not IList<byte[]> and it does not support JavaCast. MDeviceData does support it, however. I'm seeing different datatypes in runtime (or debug-time) and different from Intellisense. I'll try cast MDeviceData to a re-created DeviceData class in .NET with a different name with List<byte[]> instead of ArrayList<byte[]> and let you know how it goes. In any case, thank you for all your contributions, have been really enlighting. Any more suggestions are also welcomed.

Comment: @ManosGeorgoudakis well, `IList` is just the interface it implements. You could try to explicitly cast `MDataBlood` to a `IJavaObject` and if the casting succeeds then you could call `JavaCast` on it.

Comment: The suggested cast can't be used because JavaCast requires a TResult compatible with IJavaObject, and clearly, List<byte> isn't. I also implemented the DeviceData class as the descendant of Java.Lang.Object, implementing IJavaObject, with no success too. The closest I got was to cast the object to Java.Lang.Object and then serialize it to a byte array. The last 12 bytes of the array are the ones I need. Now I'm looking for a more elegant solution. I suspect that Xamarin mishandles objects in ArrayLists.

Comment: @ManosGeorgoudakis What if you try to cast it to a non generic `IEnumerable`? I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Nope, IEnumerable does not implement the IJavaObject so, it does not allow it. Problem is that Android's Java ArrayList<byte[]> is translated to IList<Object> most likely because, for some reason in Xamarin, ArrayList is without data type, unlike IList. Don't know how debugger figures this out though.

Comment: @ManosGeorgoudakis My bad, forgot about that. I've edited the answer again using `JavaList<byte[]>` (or `JavaList<object>`) and added a contingency plan which I think is a little bit less unorthodox than your current solution.  Yet another thing you could try is to cast `MDeviceData` to a custom interface of yours which extends `IJAvaObject` and has a `JavaList<byte[]> MDataBlood` property.

Comment: Yes, that did it! Although I had tried something similar with no success, two consecutive casts (to IJavaObject and then to byte array did the trick. Thank you very much, well played!

Comment: No prob! :) Specifically, which cast worked for you? `JavaList<byte[]>` or `JavaList<object>`? What about disabling the linker?

Comment: JavaList<byte[]> did it. I didn't touch the linker at all, just these two lines. The backup solution I had come up with was to cast MBloodData[i] as Java Object (Java.Lang.Object) and then serialize it to a 1byte array. This produced, due to overhead info, 39 bytes instead of 12 I was expecting. The last 12 of the 39-byte array were the ones I was looking for so it was easy to obtain the start index (arraySize-12). Of course, your prettier solution provides just the 12 bytes stored in the first place.